# how to modify string with scanner?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I already have a string let's say

```
String abc = "Stack";
```

Now, I want to modify this string using scanner class **only** ! So, user should to able to see existing string on console and then he can edit that string.
I tried this, but then it just replaces the existing string.

```
System.out.println("Edit the below string");
System.out.println(abc);
abc = scanner.nextLine();
```

How would I achieve it ?

Comment: If you read the documentation of the String class one of the first things you will read is ["Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - So nothing can edit a String. You can always just assign the variable to a new String.

Comment: Strings in java are immutable, And the line read from Scanner is also a String and therefore immutable. So you can only replace one string with another in Java. 
And to the User, in your case, the strings printed in the console are in  no way editable in the first place!

Comment: Thats fine if I cannot edit the String I can use either StringBuffer or StringBuilder. But thats not the point. I want to just edit this String on console.

Comment: Simple answer - You can't  achieve it. You can't edit this String on console.

Comment: Use `StringBuffer`, which is an array of characters, essentially making it mutable

Answer (score -2):

Well the issue is you shouldn't with just a String. Your problem is the reason **StringBuffer** was created. Ideal solution:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("Stack");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    buffer.append(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}

String abc = buffer.toString(); //if you really need to save it to variable 'abc' for some reason.
```

Here is a terrible example if you hate your computer and can only user a String.

```
String abc = "Stack";
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    abc += scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(abc);
}
```

The above is a terrible solution for memory reason.

I hope this helps

Comment: Any reason for the '-1'?

Comment: Because getLine doesn't even exist in Java. You clearly didn't even test run your code. You have this "scanner" variable that was never declared. And even if you do initialize it as a Scanner object, this code does nothing like what you claim it does. Test run your code before posting it here.

Comment: Not sure how I could have made that mistake but, I fixed it. Hope that helps.